# Create a unique identifier for PHP generated divs?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

Not sure of the best way to go about this, but essentially I am using PHP to pull from a SQL database of posts, performed in a for loop. This is my code so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT *FROM $tbl_name";
$lastPostID = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql))-1;

//CREATE BLOG POSTS
for ($currPostID = $lastPostID; $currPostID >= 0; $currPostID--){
       $sqlQuery =  "SELECT title, content FROM $tbl_name WHERE postID = '$currPostID'";
       $title = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sqlQuery))['title'];
       $content = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sqlQuery))['content'];
       echo '<div class = "row">';
            echo '<div class = "col-md-12">';
                  echo '<h4 class = "widget-title">' .$title. '</h4>';
                  echo '<p>' .nl2br($content). '</p>';
                  echo '<hr class = "blogborder">';
            echo '</div>';
       echo '</div>';
}
```

As you can see, I'm placing each entry in the SQL database into its own div container on the page. However, I'm also thinking that in the future I'll want to create an "edit" feature for these posts, which requires that I be able to uniquely identify the post in my SQL database.

Right now I'm considering adding in an additional div container solely to store the postID (which is the primary key in SQL) of each post. As such, in the for loop, there would be an extra line:

```
echo '<div class = "idNum">' .$postID. '</div>';
```

Something along those lines (which ends up being visually hidden via CSS), and then use jQuery to grab the ID value using this.val(), which would then allow me to run an AJAX query editing the post.

However, I feel like there is a better, cleaner way to do this and was wondering if you all had any input?

Comment: You can use of a *random string* for the name of `id`.

Comment: btw, stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use PDO / MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 2):

No need for an extra element. Use a `data-` attribute on each repeating module.

These are easily read using jQuery data() method

```
echo '<div class = "row" data-id="' .$postID. '">';
```

Then for an example can use something like:

```
$('.widget-title').click(function(){
    alert( $(this).closest('.row').data('id') );
 });
```